# Nginx Reverse proxy leading to Redirect loop

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I have a load balancer (Nginx) and another Apache server which is hosting a wordpress blog (at /blog). I want all my traffic on my load balancer at `/blog` to go to this Apache server. I have the following settings:

```
upstream main_app  {
  server main_app_address;
}

upstream blog {
  server blog_address;
}

server {
   server_name appname.com;
   return 301 http://www.appname.com$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name appname.com;

  location / {
    client_max_body_size 8M;
    proxy_pass  http://main_app;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
  }

  location /blog {
    proxy_pass http://blog/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
  }

}
```

This shows me the directory listing on the Apache server at `/` where I can see the `/blog` however that is not what I want, I want it to show the contents of `/blog` from the Apache server.

If I remove the trailing slash in the /blog location directive I end up with endless redirects.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this by replacing:

```
proxy_pass http://blog/;
```

with

```
proxy_pass http://blog;
```

Please read the docs: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

Comment: solved my redirect issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and it was solved when I commented out `proxy_set_header Host $host;`

Comment: solved my issue. my multitenant web app was loading alright but the web app internally failed to find the tenant by subdomain which is in the url that where passed from proxy_pass. commenting `proxy_set_header Host $host;` solved the issue.